# Skeleton loader component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to VueJS, and I'm coming to you to find out if what I've done is feasible or not.

Instead of having old data, while loading components, I prefer to display a preloader.
I liked the idea of a skeletons loader, rather than a simple spinner.

Right now I have a state in the store, which is null by default, I have a mutation to set the loading, and a getter.
To avoid visual bugs, from the router, with a beforeEach, I initialize the loading state to true, so that by default the components start loading !

Then, in my view, I import the Loader component, with its svg and style.
And I place it over the component that needs to be displayed, with a simple condition v-if="!getLoading" and v-if="getLoading".

The problem is that I feel like I'm tinkering with the blind, the beforeach and displaying this component with a condition?

I would be reassured if someone can give me some advice, or approve this method of doing!

Here is the code of a simple Loader component

```html
<template>
    <content-loader
        :height="78"
        :width="390"
        :speed="4"
        primaryColor="#f2f6fe"
        secondaryColor="#e0eafa"
    >
        <rect x="9" y="20" rx="4" ry="4" width="142" height="13" />
        <rect x="316.38" y="5.38" rx="5" ry="5" width="68" height="68" />
        <rect x="9" y="46" rx="4" ry="4" width="75.26" height="13.26" />
    </content-loader>
</template>

<script>
import { ContentLoader } from "vue-content-loader"

export default {
    components: {
        ContentLoader
    }
}
</script>
```

The store code

```html
const state = {
    loading: null,
}

const mutations = {
    SET_LOADING: (state, payload) => {
        state.loading = payload;
    },
}

const getters = {
    getLoading(state) {
        return state.loading;
    }
}
```

Example of utilisation in my view : with condition

```html
<div class="col-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 col-md-6" v-if="getLoading"> // the condition
                        <div class="card animate-up-2">
                            <div class="card-body">
                            // the component
                                <StatsLoader></StatsLoader>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 col-md-6" v-if="!getLoading"> // the condition
                        <div class="card animate-up-2">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                    <div>
                                        <h3 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">5 %</h3>
                                        <div class="d-flex d-sm-block d-lg-flex align-items-end">
                                            <p class="mb-0 mr-2 text-muted">API usage</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="avatar avatar-lg">
                                            <div class="avatar-title sred sbg-soft-red rounded">
                                                <i class="fad fa-project-diagram"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is a global loader being used on all the routes, you can wrap it in a component and use that component everywhere. Use [named slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots) to manage your template.
An example of a Loader component:

> Loader.vue

```
<template>
   <div>
     <slot name='loading' v-if='getLoading'>
        <StatsLoader></StatsLoader>
     </slot>
     <slot name='content v-if='!getLoading'></slot>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
  import StatsLoader from '@/components/StatsLoader.vue';
  export default {
    name: 'Loader',
    props: {
      isLoading: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: null
      }
    },
    computed: {
      getLoading() {
        return this.isLoading === null ? this.$store.state.loading : this.isLoading;
      }
    },
    components: {
      StatsLoader
    }
  }
</script>
```

Also, it would useful to register this component globally so you don't need to include it all the routes. You can do that using `Vue.component` in your main entry file.

```js
import Loader from '@/components/Loader.vue';

Vue.component('Loader', Loader);
```

And you can rewrite your current component template like this:

```html
<Loader>
  <template v-slot:loader>
    <!-- Use a different loader here for this page maybe -->
  </template>
  <template v-slot:content>
    <div class="card animate-up-2">
      <div class="card-body">
         <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <div>
               <h3 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">5 %</h3>
               <div class="d-flex d-sm-block d-lg-flex align-items-end">
                  <p class="mb-0 mr-2 text-muted">API usage</p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div>
               <div class="avatar avatar-lg">
                  <div class="avatar-title sred sbg-soft-red rounded">
                     <i class="fad fa-project-diagram"></i>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </template>
</Loader>
```

Also you can use `<Loader :is-loading='isPageLoading' />` in case you don't want to rely on the global loader.

Comment: The SVG are different, I adapt it according to the shape, so I have 1 component for each SVG.

I use this to make one component: 
https://create-vue-content-loader.netlify.app/

And if I use the slots, I'm going to get a lot of SVG in my view, and I think it's even less clean, what do you think?

Edit: I had badly looked at the structure, if I understand well, the custom svg can remain while composing, and will be included in the slot!

Comment: So basically you're creating a skeleton for all the components you're creating correct? In that case, I'd suggest a similar pattern. You write your normal component code, and once it's done, wrap it in a `Loader` component with your skeleton loader in the `loader` slot. You can also provide that specific loader with a different conditional to render content.

Comment: If I understand well, I need to create a first component with 2 slots, One for the custom SVG and one other with the real content to display (html structure) and after that, I put this in the view and I place the SVG on the first slot, and the html content in the second. The conditions for isLoading or not, in the view with the component which contains the 2 slots, that's right ? (sorry for my bad english :( )

Comment: Yes, you're almost there. Only the `isLoading` condition is a global boolean available in all pages. If the `isLoading` is dependent on something in your page, you can pass it down to the `<Loader />` component. Have to modify this current answer to facilitate accepting a loading condition as a prop, and fallback to the store if nothing is defined.